# jquery-issue with load(): works with Firefox and Safari, not with Chrome, Opera and IE

Tags: jquery, toggle, fadein, scrollto

May somebody could take a look at this. With Firefox and Safari it works, but not with Chrome, IE and Oopera... and I don't know why.

After a click in a table, it fetches the id and will build a url which will be loaded. Actually I will pass arrays with load to the php, but for the demonstration, I guess this example makes more sense:

```
var id1 = "1";
var id2 = "2";

oTable.$('tr').click(function () {
    isClicked = $(this).data('clicked');
    if (isClicked) {
        isClicked = false;
    } else {
        isClicked = true;
    }
    $(this).data('clicked', isClicked);

    if (isClicked) {
        id2 = id1;
        id1 = oTable.fnGetData(this, 0);
        $(window).scrollTo('#ma', {
            duration: 1000
        });
        $("#ma").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $("#ma").fadeIn('slow').load("index" + id1 + id2 + ".html");
        });
    } else {
        id2 = id1;
        id1 = oTable.fnGetData(this, 0);
        $(window).scrollTo('#ma', {
            duration: 1000
        });
        $("#ma").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $("#ma").fadeIn('slow').load("index" + id1 + id2 + ".html");
        });
    }
});
```

What happens in all browsers: After a click in a row it will scroll to the id #ma (so the functions work in a toggle way), but only Firefox and Safari will load the file.

What's wrong with it? Or is it an issue with the ids in the url, and will be okay, when I push it as arrays to the php? So far I tried it only in local modus.

Comment: Open your console and see if the request happens at all, check the URL etc.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///XYZ/index31.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: ...that was with Chrome. Opera has a bit more information to this issue: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: You're not using a webserver are you ?

Comment: Nope, in local modus... so far. Just a win-folder. On webserver it will be no problem?

Comment: You've just discovered that you can't make ajax requests from a `file::` protocol. Download a webserver like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) etc. and it should work just fine.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Actually no mistake of my script, that was the strange point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) gave the hint: The script is fine, but I "can't make ajax requests from a file:: protocol". I tried to load the file from a local folder. Obviously the 3 browsers don't like it... and Firefox and Safari just ignore it.